# jQuery datatable with no data from database

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, datatables

I populate a jQuery datatable with info stored in a customer SQL' table for that purpose I've created a very simple query(this is an example):

```
select Myfield1, Myfield2, Myfield3 from customersTbl where id=@id;
```

the id value is the same for all the customers of a specific area, once the datatable is populated the user can select a record and update or delete the info, I don't have any problems with the update action but when it comes to delete it can happens that the user deletes all of the records of customers of a specific area so in the datatble the id field won´t have any value and the datatable returns an error because the query doesn't retrieve any value.

How can I manage the fact that a user can delete all of the records(therefore the id value) and thata the query thata populates the datatable won't return any data?

[image]

this is my datatable script code

```
 $('#myTable').DataTable({
     searching: false,
     paging: true,
     responsive: true,
     ordering: false,
     bInfo: false,
     bLengthChange: false,
     processing: true,
     info: false,
     deferRender: true,
     orderMulti: false,
     "ajax": {
         "url": "../home/CargarTabla?id=" + noDocumento,
         "type": "GET",
         "datatype": "json"
     },
     "columns": [
         { "data": "nombres", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
         { "data": "apellidos", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
         { "data": "dui", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
         { "data": "numero_isss", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
         { "data": "cargo_participante", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
         { "data": "genero", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
         { "data": "nivel_puesto", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
         { "defaultContent": " <a href='#' id='select'>Modificar</a>  ", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false }
     ],
```

this is the code that loads the datatable, is an action in a MVC C# controller and it makes a call to a WCF service

```
public ActionResult CargarTabla(string id)
{
    ProxyGFC.ServiceGFCClient cliente = new ProxyGFC.ServiceGFCClient();
    List<WcfService.Entidades.EmpleadoDatatable> info = new List<WcfService.Entidades.EmpleadoDatatable>();
    info = cliente.CargarDatatable(id);
    List<GFC_Site.Models.EmpleadoDatatableMVC> lista = new List<GFC_Site.Models.EmpleadoDatatableMVC>();
    foreach (WcfService.Entidades.EmpleadoDatatable p in info)
    {
        EmpleadoDatatableMVC dato = new EmpleadoDatatableMVC();
        dato.nombres = p.nombres;
        dato.apellidos = p.apellidos;
        dato.dui = p.dui;
        dato.numero_isss = p.numero_isss;
        dato.cargo_participante = p.cargo_participante;
        dato.genero = p.genero;
        dato.nivel_puesto = p.nivel_puesto;
        lista.Add(dato);
    }
    return Json(new { data = lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: If all the customers share an id and you are deleting by id, then that makes sense.  Do you have a different, unique, identifier you can use?

Comment: No sir, the id is the common value for all the customers

Comment: Add your table structure to the question - you will have to find something other than ID to delete by.

Comment: Why don't you just check for null before binding value to datatable?

Comment: @JenR i just added the image of the field of the table, the correlativo field is autoincrement(integer 1 by 1), the field numero_docu is the id and all the others fields depends on the customers (so never will be the same)

Comment: @KarthikGanesan thanks, How should I do that?

Comment: @PabloMayora can you show how you are making calls to your server side function? and how you are binding data to  your datatable

Comment: @KarthikGanesan yes, I just edited my question.

Comment: check this link https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent

Comment: from here https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data, this is what they say "undefined - the columns.defaultContent value will be used. If there is no default content specified, an error will be given."

Comment: @KarthikGanesan thanks, so that means that if there is not any value form the database, the th elemts of the HTML table will be show ?

Comment: yes, that is how it works